# Is it possible to display speed dial items in the foreground?

Tags: css, primeng, speed-dial

I have a table that has speed dial in each row.
[Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krf8X.png)

When the items are displayed they hide behind the next dial down below.
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiUkv.png)

Is it possible to make them appear in the foreground?

I know I can change the direction of their appearance but I would prefer if it goes down.

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: I'm not allowed to but it's basically this:
`
<p-table>
<tr>
...
<p-speedDial direction="down" [model]="items" showIcon="pi pi-ellipsis-h">
               </p-speedDial>
</p-table>
`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's as far as I could go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/gtdpru-ecp7pj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fspeed-dial-linear-demo.html. I'm not sure whether it's possible to fix the scrollbar seeing as the component has no options to specify something like `attachTo="body"`. Why don't you use popup menu though: https://primeng.org/menu#popup?

Comment: Didn't know about popup. It looks like the better option. Thanks